# How to check if a string contains text from an array of substrings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, substring, contains

Pretty straight forward. In javascript, I need to check if a string contains any substrings held in an array.

Comment: Isn't there a `map()` function in the new HTML5-JavaScript-version? I remember having read something on that topic...

Comment: @Martin: Good point, not `map` so much as `some`. `some` would help, but you'd have to pass it a function.

Answer (score 471, accepted):

There's nothing built-in that will do that for you, you'll have to write a function for it, although it can be just a callback to the `some` array method.

Two approaches for you:

- Array `some` method
- Regular expression

#### Array `some`

The array `some` method (added in ES5) makes this quite straightforward:

```
if (substrings.some(function(v) { return str.indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
    // There's at least one
}
```

Even better with an arrow function and the newish `includes` method (both ES2015+):

```
if (substrings.some(v => str.includes(v))) {
    // There's at least one
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const substrings = ["one", "two", "three"];
let str;

// Setup
console.log(`Substrings: ${substrings}`);

// Try it where we expect a match
str = "this has one";
if (substrings.some(v => str.includes(v))) {
    console.log(`Match using "${str}"`);
} else {
    console.log(`No match using "${str}"`);
}

// Try it where we DON'T expect a match
str = "this doesn't have any";
if (substrings.some(v => str.includes(v))) {
    console.log(`Match using "${str}"`);
} else {
    console.log(`No match using "${str}"`);
}
```

#### Regular expression

If you *know* the strings don't contain any of the characters that are special in regular expressions, then you can cheat a bit, like this:

```
if (new RegExp(substrings.join("|")).test(string)) {
    // At least one match
}
```

...which creates a regular expression that's a series of *alternations* for the substrings you're looking for (e.g., `one|two`) and tests to see if there are matches for any of them, but if any of the substrings contains any characters that are special in regexes (`*`, `[`, etc.), you'd have to escape them first and you're better off just doing the boring loop instead. For info about escaping them, see [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript).

Live Example:

```js
const substrings = ["one", "two", "three"];
let str;

// Setup
console.log(`Substrings: ${substrings}`);

// Try it where we expect a match
str = "this has one";
if (new RegExp(substrings.join("|")).test(str)) {
    console.log(`Match using "${str}"`);
} else {
    console.log(`No match using "${str}"`);
}

// Try it where we DON'T expect a match
str = "this doesn't have any";
if (new RegExp(substrings.join("|")).test(str)) {
    console.log(`Match using "${str}"`);
} else {
    console.log(`No match using "${str}"`);
}
```

Comment: using `.some` how would you return the one that match?

Comment: @sreginogemoh - You wouldn't use `some` in that case, you'd use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which returns the first element for which your callback returns a truthy value, or `undefined` if the callback never returns a truthy value.

Comment: yeah that's what I did, however I thought that `some` might handle that....

Comment: @sreginogemoh - Only if you do something like `let x; if (array.some((v) => { if (/*... v matches condition ... */) { x = v; return true; } return false; })) { /*... use `x` here ... */ }` but it's much simpler and more idiomatic to use `find` in that case. The only real reason for doing what I showed there is for when `undefined` is actually in the array **and** it's what you want to find. (With `find` you wouldn't know if you'd found it, or not found anything. With the above, you can tell the difference). Very rare case...

Comment: https://jsben.ch/NdFDq

find/some & includes are (not by much) faster than the other solutions, other than RegExp which can be up to 2x slower.

Answer (score 132):

**One line solution**

```
substringsArray.some(substring=>yourBigString.includes(substring))
```

Returns `true/false` if substring `exists/doesn't exist`

**Needs ES6 support**

Comment: You kids...back when I was a kid we had to use these things called 'for' loops, and you had to use multiple lines and know whether your array was 1 or zero based, yeah...half the time you got it wrong and had to debug and look out for a little bugger called 'i'.

Comment: @aamarks The gold old dayss...

Comment: I like short answers.

Answer (score 56):

```
var yourstring = 'tasty food'; // the string to check against


var substrings = ['foo','bar'],
    length = substrings.length;
while(length--) {
   if (yourstring.indexOf(substrings[length])!=-1) {
       // one of the substrings is in yourstring
   }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

```
function containsAny(str, substrings) {
    for (var i = 0; i != substrings.length; i++) {
       var substring = substrings[i];
       if (str.indexOf(substring) != - 1) {
         return substring;
       }
    }
    return null; 
}

var result = containsAny("defg", ["ab", "cd", "ef"]);
console.log("String was found in substring " + result);
```

Comment: Plus it returns the first occurence of the word in the string, which is very helpful. Not only a true/false.

Comment: what is the es6 equivalent?

Answer (score 24):

For people Googling,

The solid answer should be.

```
const substrings = ['connect', 'ready'];
const str = 'disconnect';
if (substrings.some(v => str === v)) {
   // Will only return when the `str` is included in the `substrings`
}
```

Comment: or shorter: if (substrings.some(v => v===str)) {

Comment: Note that this is an answer to a slightly different question, which asks if a string **contains** text from an array of substrings. This code checks if a string **is** one of the substrings. Depends on what is meant by "contains" I suppose.

Answer (score 21):

Here's what is (IMO) **by far** the best solution. It's a modern (ES6) solution that:

- is efficient (one line!)
- avoids for loops
- unlike the `some()` function that's used in the other answers, this one doesn't just return a boolean (true/false)
- instead, it either returns the substring (if it was found in the array), or returns undefined
- goes a step further and allows you to choose whether or not you need partial substring matches (examples below)

**Enjoy!**

```
const arrayOfStrings = ['abc', 'def', 'xyz'];
const str = 'abc';
const found = arrayOfStrings.find(v => (str === v));
```

Here, `found` would be set to 'abc' in this case. This will work for **exact** string matches.

If instead you use:

```
const found = arrayOfStrings.find(v => str.includes(v));
```

Once again, `found` would be set to 'abc' in this case. This doesn't allow for partial matches, so if str was set to 'ab', `found` would be undefined.

And, if you want partial matches to work, simply flip it so you're doing:

```
const found = arrayOfStrings.find(v => v.includes(str));
```

instead. So if str was set to 'ab', `found` would be set to 'abc'.

**Easy peasy!**

Answer (score 8):

```
var str = "texttexttext";
var arr = ["asd", "ghj", "xtte"];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (str.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {
        // str contains arr[i]
    }
}
```

edit: 
If the order of the tests doesn't matter, you could use this (with only one loop variable):

```
var str = "texttexttext";
var arr = ["asd", "ghj", "xtte"];
for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (str.indexOf(arr[i]) != -1) {
        // str contains arr[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first example doesn't need the `len` variable, just check `i < arr.length`.

Comment: the only answer that returns the matched array string. this should have been included in previous example for completeness sake

Answer (score 5):

```js
const str = 'Does this string have one or more strings from the array below?';
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

const contains = arr.some(element => {
  if (str.includes(element)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(contains); // true
```

Comment: Even shorter method: `arr.some(element => str.includes(element) ? true : false)`

Answer (score 4):

```
substringsArray.every(substring=>yourBigString.indexOf(substring) === -1)
```

For full support ;)

Answer (score 4):

For full support (additionally to @ricca 's [verions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61122664/4992248)).

```js
wordsArray = ['hello', 'to', 'nice', 'day']
yourString = 'Hello. Today is a nice day'.toLowerCase()
result = wordsArray.every(w => yourString.includes(w))
console.log('result:', result)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the array is not large, you could just loop and check the string against each substring individually using `indexOf()`. Alternatively you could construct a regular expression with substrings as alternatives, which may or may not be more efficient.

Comment: Let's say we have a list of 100 substrings. Which way would be more efficient: RegExp or loop?

Answer (score 3):

Javascript function to search an array of tags or keywords using a search string or an array of search strings. (Uses **ES5** *some* array method and **ES6** *arrow functions*)

```
// returns true for 1 or more matches, where 'a' is an array and 'b' is a search string or an array of multiple search strings
function contains(a, b) {
    // array matches
    if (Array.isArray(b)) {
        return b.some(x => a.indexOf(x) > -1);
    }
    // string match
    return a.indexOf(b) > -1;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var a = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
var b = ["a","b"];
if ( contains(a, b) ) {
    // 1 or more matches found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is super late, but I just ran into this problem. In my own project I used the following to check if a string was in an array:

```
["a","b"].includes('a')     // true
["a","b"].includes('b')     // true
["a","b"].includes('c')     // false
```

This way you can take a predefined array and check if it contains a string:

```
var parameters = ['a','b']
parameters.includes('a')    // true
```

Comment: this is the cleanest answer here. many thanks!

Comment: the question here is not string in an array but strings in an array in a sentence

Answer (score 3):

Best answer is here:
This is case insensitive as well

```
    var specsFilter = [.....];
    var yourString = "......";

    //if found a match
    if (specsFilter.some((element) => { return new RegExp(element, "ig").test(yourString) })) {
        // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm suggesting that you go and extend/modify `String`'s prototype, but this is what I've done:

[String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
String.prototype.includes = function (includes) {
    console.warn("String.prototype.includes() has been modified.");
    return function (searchString, position) {
        if (searchString instanceof Array) {
            for (var i = 0; i < searchString.length; i++) {
                if (includes.call(this, searchString[i], position)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return includes.call(this, searchString, position);
        }
    }
}(String.prototype.includes);

console.log('"Hello, World!".includes("foo");',          "Hello, World!".includes("foo")           ); // false
console.log('"Hello, World!".includes(",");',            "Hello, World!".includes(",")             ); // true
console.log('"Hello, World!".includes(["foo", ","])',    "Hello, World!".includes(["foo", ","])    ); // true
console.log('"Hello, World!".includes(["foo", ","], 6)', "Hello, World!".includes(["foo", ","], 6) ); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

building on T.J Crowder's answer

using escaped RegExp to test for "at least once" occurrence, of at least one of the substrings.

```js
function buildSearch(substrings) {
  return new RegExp(
    substrings
    .map(function (s) {return s.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');})
    .join('{1,}|') + '{1,}'
  );
}


var pattern = buildSearch(['hello','world']);

console.log(pattern.test('hello there'));
console.log(pattern.test('what a wonderful world'));
console.log(pattern.test('my name is ...'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Drawing from T.J. Crowder's solution, I created a prototype to deal with this problem:

```
Array.prototype.check = function (s) {
  return this.some((v) => {
    return s.indexOf(v) >= 0;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using underscore.js or lodash.js, you can do the following on an array of strings:

```
var contacts = ['Billy Bob', 'John', 'Bill', 'Sarah'];

var filters = ['Bill', 'Sarah'];

contacts = _.filter(contacts, function(contact) {
    return _.every(filters, function(filter) { return (contact.indexOf(filter) === -1); });
});

// ['John']
```

And on a single string:

```
var contact = 'Billy';
var filters = ['Bill', 'Sarah'];

_.every(filters, function(filter) { return (contact.indexOf(filter) >= 0); });

// true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a long list of substrings consisting of full "words" separated by spaces or any other common character, you can be a little clever in your search.

First divide your string into groups of X, then X+1, then X+2, ..., up to Y. X and Y should be the number of words in your substring with the fewest and most words respectively. For example if X is 1 and Y is 4, "Alpha Beta Gamma Delta" becomes:

"Alpha" "Beta" "Gamma" "Delta"

"Alpha Beta" "Beta Gamma" "Gamma Delta"

"Alpha Beta Gamma" "Beta Gamma Delta"

"Alpha Beta Gamma Delta"

If X would be 2 and Y be 3, then you'd omit the first and last row.

Now you can search on this list quickly if you insert it into a Set (or a Map), much faster than by string comparison.

The downside is that you can't search for substrings like "ta Gamm". Of course you could allow for that by splitting by character instead of by word, but then you'd often need to build a massive Set and the time/memory spent doing so outweighs the benefits.

Answer (score 1):

```
convert_to_array = function (sentence) {
     return sentence.trim().split(" ");
};

let ages = convert_to_array ("I'm a programmer in javascript writing script");

function confirmEnding(string) {
let target = "ipt";
    return  (string.substr(-target.length) === target) ? true : false;
}

function mySearchResult() {
return ages.filter(confirmEnding);
}

mySearchResult();
```

you could check like this and return an array of the matched words using filter

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem like this. I had a URL, I wanted to check if the link ends in an image format or other file format, having an array of images format. Here is what I did:

```
const imagesFormat = ['.jpg','.png','.svg']
const link = "https://res.cloudinary.com/***/content/file_padnar.pdf"
const isIncludes = imagesFormat.some(format => link.includes(format))
    
// false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         var list = ["bad", "words", "include"] 
         var sentence = $("#comments_text").val()

         $.each(list, function( index, value ) {
           if (sentence.indexOf(value) > -1) {
                console.log(value)
            }
         });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input id="comments_text" value="This is a bad, with include test"> 
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let obj = [{name : 'amit'},{name : 'arti'},{name : 'sumit'}];
let input = 'it';
```

Use filter :

```js
obj.filter((n)=> n.name.trim().toLowerCase().includes(input.trim().toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk thnx

Answer (score -1):

```js
var str = "A for apple"
var subString = ["apple"]

console.log(str.includes(subString))
```