# How to check if a string contains any character from another string?

Tags: javascript

How can I determine if any individual character in `src` matches any individual character in `restricted`? I have this JS method which does the job, but I'd like to improve it if I can:

```
function CheckRestricted(src, restricted)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < restricted.length; j++)
        {
            if (src.charAt(i) == restricted.charAt(j))
                return false;
        }            
    }

    return true;
}
```

If this were C#, I could achieve this with LINQ in a single line:

```
bool CheckRestricted(string src, string restricted)
{
    return src.Any(s => restricted.Contains(s));
}
```

Is there some sort of similar functionality in JS that I'm unaware of?

**EDIT:** Sample use case:

```
CheckRestricted("ABCD", "!+-=;:'`"); //true
CheckRestricted("ABCD!", "!+-=;:'`"); //false
```

It is predominantly used to disallow 'special characters'.

Comment: please add some use cases.

Comment: @NinaScholz edited my post with 2 samples.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript. Checking if string contains text from an array of substrings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/javascript-checking-if-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function CheckRestricted(src, restricted) {
   return !src.split("").some(ch => restricted.indexOf(ch) !== -1);
}
```

Comment: The second `.split("")` is not necessary

Comment: You can use `String.prototype.includes()`

Comment: This seems to work for me, at least it does using a web-based JS compiler. For some reason Visual Studio 2013 gives a `syntax error` on `=>`? But what does VS know about JS, anyways :)

Comment: @Andreas thx, looks nicer that way and more efficient. And yeah missunderstood when it should return true, changed

Comment: @sab669 => sintax is ecmascript 6, you could always do the old function (ch) {return estricted.indexOf(ch) !== -1}

Comment: @juvian See here: http://js.do/code/146954 . The third one should pass validation

Comment: @sab669 that is not the same function I made. There you are checking if ch is a substring of restricted, which is false in all cases