# Check whether an array includes a string but ignore rest other letters in that string

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, string

I have a variable like,

```
var url = "/login/user";
```

And I have an array like,

```
var x = ["login", "resetpassword", "authenticate"];
```

Now I need to check, whether that **url** string is present in an array of string. As we can see that login is present in an array but when i do **x.indexOf(url)**, it always receive false because the field url has rest other letters also. So now how can I ingnore those letters while checking a string in an array and return true?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.some` over the array instead:

```js
var url = "/login/user";
var x = ["login", "resetpassword", "authenticate"];

if (x.some(str => url.includes(str))) {
  console.log('something in X is included in URL');
}
```

Or, if the substring you're looking for is always between the first two slashes in the `url` variable, then extract that substring first, and use `.includes`:

```js
var url = "/login/user";
var x = ["login", "resetpassword", "authenticate"];

var foundStr = url.split('/')[1];

if (x.includes(foundStr)) {
  console.log('something in X is included in URL');
}
```

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

One way is to split url with `/` character and than use `some`

```js
var url = "/login/user";
var x = ["login", "resetpassword", "authenticate"];

let urlSplitted = url.split('/')

let op = urlSplitted.some(e=> x.includes(e))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You could join the given words with a pipe (as or operator in regex), generate a regular expression and test against the string.

This works as long as you do not have some characters with special meanings.

```js
var url = "/login/user",
    x = ["login", "resetpassword", "authenticate"];

console.log(new RegExp(x.join('|')).test(url));
```

Comment: resulting in `/login|resetpassword|authenticate/.test("/login/user")` - clever

Comment: Note: It will return true on authenticate in  `"/logged/authenticateduser"`

Comment: as the other solutions.

Comment: Sure. But yours seemed the cleverest. Dupe of this though https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582621/295783