# Find word in sentence in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have set lists

example:

```
const answerList = [{index: 2, answer: nice}, {index: 5, answer: sunday} ...]
```

like that

and I have a sentence

example:

"hi i'm theo nice to meet you. how are you"

so I want to check if there is a correct answer in the sentence and if find it, return answerList set

example:

```
return value is [{index: 2, answer: nice}]
```

Because there is the word "nice" in the sentence.

Can someone tell me a good way?

Comment: Can you clarify more, you want to see from the list of words, which ones are in the sentence?

Comment: Too similar to this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [**Array.prototype.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**String.prototype.includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
const answerList = [{index: 2, answer: 'nice'}, {index: 5, answer: 'sunday'}];
const sentence = "hi i'm theo nice to meet you. how are you";
var res = answerList.filter(a => sentence.includes(a.answer));
console.log(res);
```