# How to make a variable that can be detected as multiple items

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
   if(msg.content.includes(“hi” or? “hello” or? “hey”)){
      msg.reply(“hi” or? “hello” or? “hey”);
   }
})
```

I’m coding a discord bot on my server and I want to add a feature where it responds to people. I want to make it so that my bot can detect multiple ways a user greets and have it greet them back.

Comment: Can you elaborate on `can be detected as multiple items` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
const greetings = ['hi', 'hello', 'hey'];

if (greetings.includes(msg.content)) {...}
```

Comment: It doesn’t allow users to post other things in the message for the bot to respond

Answer (score 0):

```
const greetings = {
"hi": "hi",
"hello":"hello"
.....
}

if (greetings[msg.content]) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to check if a string contains text from an array of substrings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript)

```
if (substrings.some(v => str.includes(v))) {
    // There's at least one
}
```