# Using a method includes() checking string for occurrences of characters represented in array is returning true - removing characters from a string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, include

I'm building a URL slug generator and I need to have the behavior be that if what's inputted is:

`Ok Now Let's Do This & See`

the output needs to be

`ok-now-lets-do-this-see`

Removing the `&` , `'`, and `,` characters

```js
let newStr;

function slugifyString(str) {
  let forbiddenChars = ["&", "'", ","];
    newStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-');
  if (newStr.includes(forbiddenChars) > -1) {
    console.log('a forbidden character is present')
  }
}

document.getElementById('slug-a-string-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let inputStr = document.getElementById('string-to-slug').value
  slugifyString(inputStr);
  document.getElementById('slugged-string').innerHTML = newStr;
});
```

```css
#slugged-string {
  color: green;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="slug-a-string-form" action="POST">
  <input type="text" id="string-to-slug" placeholder="enter the string to want to slug here...">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="slugged-string"></div>
```

This works with a string like:

`Testing This Out With Something TitleLike`

And it slugifies, but it's saying that a forbidden character is present when it's not. Why is that happening?

[How to check if a string contains text from an array of substrings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript)

I tweaked it a bit and tried this:

```js
let newStr;

function slugifyString(str) {
  let forbiddenChars = ["&", "'", ","];
    newStr = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '-');
  let forbiddenCharsLength = forbiddenChars.length;
    while(forbiddenCharsLength--) {
    if (newStr.indexOf(forbiddenChars[forbiddenCharsLength])!=-1) {
      if(forbiddenChars[forbiddenCharsLength] == "&") {
        newStr = newStr.replace("-&", '')
      } else {
        newStr = newStr.replace(forbiddenChars[forbiddenCharsLength], '')
      }
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('slug-a-string-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let inputStr = document.getElementById('string-to-slug').value
  slugifyString(inputStr);
  document.getElementById('slugged-string').innerHTML = newStr;
});
```

```css
#slugged-string {
  color: green;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="slug-a-string-form" action="POST">
  <input type="text" id="string-to-slug" placeholder="enter the string to want to slug here...">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="slugged-string"></div>
```

Based on the output of the console:

```
it is: '
it is: &
```

It appears to be looping over each iteration of a forbidden character.

Inputting in:

`Ok Now Let's Do This & See`

We get the correct output now of:

`ok-now-lets-do-this-see`

But if we say:

`Ok Now Let's Do This & That & See, what happens if we have more than one, comma`

We get:

`ok-now-lets-do-this-that-&-see-what-happens-if-we-have-more-than-one,-comma`

I'm not sure why it's not removing every character that's forbidden, since we're looping over it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

> If pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced.

I do know that it replaces it only once, but

```
while(forbiddenCharsLength--) {
    if (newStr.indexOf(forbiddenChars[forbiddenCharsLength])!=-1) {
      if(forbiddenChars[forbiddenCharsLength] == "&") {
        newStr = newStr.replace("-&", '')
      } else {
        newStr = newStr.replace(forbiddenChars[forbiddenCharsLength], '')
      }
    }
```

We're doing a while loop and executing an if command on each match so shouldn't the replace run for each instance..?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use replaceAll function instead of replace.

Comment: Ugh I always forget all the different methods, I'm accepting this one as soon as I can

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try this solution:

```js
const s = "Ok Now Let's Do This & That & See, what happens if we have more than one, comma";

const slug = s.replaceAll(/[',&]/g, '').replaceAll(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

console.log(slug);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string into an array for each letter, then remove (map to "") each forbidden letter and proceed by replacing whitespaces with -

```
  let forbiddenChars = ["&", "'", ","];
  let newStr = str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split("")
    .map(ch => forbiddenChars.includes(ch) ? '' : ch)
    .join("")
    .replace(/\s/g, '-');
```

```js
function slugifyString(str) {
  let forbiddenChars = ["&", "'", ","];
  let newStr = str
    .toLowerCase()
    .split("")
    .map(ch => forbiddenChars.includes(ch) ? '' : ch)
    .join("")
    .replace(/\s/g, '-');
  if (newStr.includes(forbiddenChars) > -1) {
    console.log('a forbidden character is present')
  }
  return newStr;
}

document.getElementById('slug-a-string-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let inputStr = document.getElementById('string-to-slug').value
  let outputStr = slugifyString(inputStr);
  document.getElementById('slugged-string').innerHTML = outputStr;
});
```

```css
#slugged-string {
  color: green;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form id="slug-a-string-form" action="POST">
  <input type="text" id="string-to-slug" placeholder="enter the string to want to slug here...">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div id="slugged-string"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array with unwanted characters/substrings and replace the final spaces with dashes.

```js
function slugify(s) {
    return ['&', ',', '\'']
        .reduce((s, c) => s.replaceAll(c, ' '), s)
        .replace(/\s+/g, '-');
}

console.log(slugify('Ok Now Let\'s Do This & That & See, what happens if we have more than one, comma'));
```