# How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript(typescript)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to make a search field, and I'm already able to do searches, but it only returns posts that are typed with the same title or are exactly the same which would not be interesting. This happens in my conditional `if (query !== post.title && query) return null`. The ideal would be to search just one word and return similar posts. I've tried using the `includes` method as follows:

`if (query !== post.title && query.includes(post.title) && query) return null`

but it didn't work.

I tried `post.title.includes(query)` too, but when I add this condition the post that I type on input is removed and it returns all the others, and if I remove the `query !== post.title` the search doesn't will work because query in my logic is the value that comes from the input.

```js
{(() => {
  if (isLoading) return <LoadingBlock />
  if (!isLoading && postList.length === 0) return <NoDataWarning text='Nenhuma postagem encontrada.' />
  return postList.map((post, index) => {
    if (query !== post.title && query.includes(post.title) && query) return null //the problem is here
    return (
      <PostContainer position={index}>
        <PostBanner />
        <PostInfoContainer>
          <span>
            <AiFillCalendar />
            {new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}
          </span>
          <span>
            <FaUserCircle />
            {`${post.firstName} ${post.lastName}`}
          </span>
        </PostInfoContainer>
        <PostTitle>{post.title}</PostTitle>
      </PostContainer>
    )
```

Full code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react'
import api from 'services/api'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { RectShape } from 'react-placeholder/lib/placeholders'
import { AiFillCalendar } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { FaUserCircle } from 'react-icons/fa'
import NoDataWarning from 'components/NoDataWarning'
import Can from 'components/Can'
import PayPlaceholder from 'components/PayPlaceholder'
import { Post } from 'types'

import { ButtonIcon, SearchGroup, SearchInput } from 'components/SearchBar/styles'
import { BiSearchAlt2 } from 'react-icons/bi'
import { Container, PostContainer, PostTitle, PostBanner, PostInfoContainer, PostGrid } from './styles'

const RegulatorioList: React.FC = () => {
  const [postList, setPostList] = useState<Post[]>([])
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('')
  const [result, setResult] = useState<Post[] | undefined>()

  const inputHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const enteredName = event.target.value
    setQuery(enteredName)
  }

  // This function is triggered when the Search buttion is clicked
  const search = () => {
    const foundItems = postList.filter(postList => postList.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()))
    setResult(foundItems)
  }

  const fetchPosts = useCallback(() => {
    api
      .get<Post[]>('posts', { params: { filterInactives: true } })
      .then(response => {
        setPostList(response.data)
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts()
    const interval = setInterval(fetchPosts, 180000)
    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [fetchPosts])

  const LoadingBlock = () => (
    <>
      {new Array(15).fill('').map(() => (
        <RectShape color='lightgray' style={{ width: '100%', height: '350px', borderRadius: '5px' }} className='text-block' />
      ))}
    </>
  )

  return (
    <Container>
      <SearchGroup position={1}>
        <SearchInput value={query} onChange={inputHandler} placeholder='Search ' />
        <ButtonIcon type='button' onClick={search}>
          <BiSearchAlt2 />
        </ButtonIcon>
      </SearchGroup>
      <PostGrid>
        {(() => {
          if (isLoading) return <LoadingBlock />
          if (!isLoading && postList.length === 0) return <NoDataWarning text='Nenhuma postagem encontrada.' />
          return postList.map((post, index) => {
            // if (post.title.includes(query) !== post.title && query) return null
            // if (query !== indexOf(post.title) && query) return null
            // if (query !== post.title && post.title.includes(post.title) && query) return null //ALL TRYS
            // if (query !== post.title && query) return null
            if (query !== post.title && query) return null
            return null
            return (
              <PostContainer position={index}>
                <PostBanner />
                <PostInfoContainer>
                  <span>
                    <AiFillCalendar />
                    {new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}
                  </span>
                  <span>
                    <FaUserCircle />
                    {`${post.firstName} ${post.lastName}`}
                  </span>
                </PostInfoContainer>
                <PostTitle>{post.title}</PostTitle>
              </PostContainer>
            )
            return (
              <Link key={post.id} to={`/regulatorio/${post.id}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none', height: '100%' }}>
                <PostContainer position={index}>
                  <PostBanner />
                  <PostInfoContainer>
                    <span>
                      <AiFillCalendar />
                      {new Date(post.createdAt).toLocaleDateString()}
                    </span>
                    <span>
                      <FaUserCircle />
                      {`${post.firstName} ${post.lastName}`}
                    </span>
                  </PostInfoContainer>
                  <PostTitle>{post.title}</PostTitle>
                </PostContainer>
              </Link>
            )
          })
        })()}
      </PostGrid>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default RegulatorioList
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string contains text from an array of substrings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript)

Comment: I saw this question I tried too but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with this conditional:

```
 if (!post.title.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) && query) return null
```