# How to compare array with words and string, but string is sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, keyword, string-comparison

help me please
How to compare string and array if there string in array return true, else false
string it in not one word, it is sentence

Here is my code

```
const keyWords = [
  "Hello",
  "hello",
  "help please",
  "Help please",
  "John",
  "john",
  "need",
  "Need"
]

var messageUser = "My name is Peter and I need help";

function check(str) {
  let newMessageUser = str.split(" ")

  for (let i = 0; i <= keyWords.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j <= newMessageUser.length; j++) {
      let answer = (keyWords[i] === newMessageUser[j]) ? true : false;

      return answer
    }
  }
}

console.log(check(messageUser))
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: Are you trying to see if each word in `messageUser` is in `keyWords`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string contains text from an array of substrings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

- array.some to check if one entry match a condition
- string.includes to check if word is include in string

```js
const keyWords = ["Hello", "hello", "help please", "Help please", "John", "john", "need", "Need"]

var messageUser = "My name is Peter and I need help";

function check(str) {
  return keyWords.some(word => messageUser.includes(word));
}

console.log(check(messageUser))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const keyWords = [
    "Hello",
    "hello",
    "help please",
    "Help please",
    "John",
    "john",
    "need",
    "Need"
]

const messageUser = "My name is Peter and I need help";

const results = keyWords.map((item) => {
    return messageUser.toLowerCase().includes(item.toLowerCase());
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that via single line of code.

```js
const keyWords = [
  "Hello",
  "hello",
  "help please",
  "Help please",
  "John",
  "john",
  "need",
  "Need"
]

var messageUser = "My name is Peter and I need help";

console.log(keyWords.map(item => messageUser.includes(item)))
```