# Is there a function like include where I can add two or more strings to search for?

Tags: javascript

Is there a function like include where I can add two or more strings to search for?

I am trying to check if my variable include some key-words listed, or from a list.

Is there any way?

the syntax of includes/indexof/etc it doesn't seem to match with what I am looking for
ex:
string.includes(searchvalue, start)

I am looking for something like:
string.includes(searchvalue, searchvalue, searchvalue)

Comment: I'm not familiar with anything built-in, but there's certainly nothing stopping you from writing a function that loops over [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and performs your logic.

Comment: There isn't such a function but you can combine [`String.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to get the desired outcome.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint that won't work because the string will not be the keyword alone, it might just _include_ the keyword somewhere.

Comment: @EnacheMarius if you know the values in advance, you could use `s.includes('aa') || s.includes('bb')` or a regex `s.match(/aa|bb/)`. Otherwise, or if it's many items, you could use `myList.some(keyword => s.includes(keyword))`.

Comment: dupllicate: [How to check if a string contains text from an array of substrings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582574/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-text-from-an-array-of-substrings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in method like string.includes() that accepts multiple search values. I prefer to use `filter()` to iterate through string and filter out the strings using `string.includes()`

```
const string = "You are looking for built-in functions.";
const searches = ["built-in", "functions"];

const found = searches.filter(search => string.includes(search));

if (found.length > 0) {
  // found in the string
  console.log('I am found here!');
}
```

Comment: [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is not the best option because it runs through the entire array and this is not needed here. The code can reach a conclusion without checking all the search strings. Sure, for a handful of search strings the difference is too small to count; it becomes important when the list of search strings is big or when the operation is performed thousands of times.

Comment: @axiac your answer uses `every()` which also runs the entire array, though is still more efficient in that it does produce an unnecessary intermediate array. You would need to use `some()` if you were looking to exit early.

Comment: [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#description) iteratively checks the array items until it finds one that does not match the predicated implemented by the callback function (i.e. until the callback function returns `false`). [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#description) works the same way as `Array.every()` but it has a different stop criterion: it quits the iteration on the first item that matches the predicate.

Comment: ... `Array.every()` combine the values returned by the callback into an `AND` expression, `Array.some()` combines them into an `OR` expression (`fn(a[0]) && fn(a[1]) && fn(a[2]) && ...` vs `fn(a[0]) || fn(a[1]) || fn(a[2]) || ...`). Both of them short-circuit the evaluation, similar to the way the `&&` and `||` operators do.

Comment: what do you suggest? - @axiac

Comment: we can also use `keywords.some(keyword => str.includes(keyword))`

Comment: It's either `.every()` or `.some()`, depending what the OP expects. The question is not clear; I think that the target string should contain all search strings, that's why I used `.every()`. `.some()` returns `true` when at least one of the search string is found. The question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear. Assuming that you want to check if a string contains all words provided in a list, a possible implementation could look like this:

```js
function includesAll(str, words) {
  return words.every((w) => str.includes(w));
}

// success
console.log(includesAll('foo bar baz', ['foo']));
console.log(includesAll('foo bar baz', ['foo', 'bar']));
console.log(includesAll('foo bar baz', ['foo', 'baz', 'bar']));
console.log(includesAll('foo bar baz', ['foo', 'oo ba', 'bar baz', ' ']));

// also success
console.log(includesAll('foo bar baz', []));

// failure, 'bad' is not included
console.log(includesAll('foo bar baz', ['foo', 'bar', 'bad']));
```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way to accomplish this task is by using regular expressions.

```js
const text = 'this is some sample text';
const values1 = ['sample', 'text'];
const values2 = ['no', 'undone'];

function multiIncludes(text, values){
  const regex = new RegExp(values.join('|'));
  return regex.test(text);
}


// if wanting to must include all
// const multiIncludes = (text, values) => values.every(value => text.includes(value));

console.log(multiIncludes(text, values1)); // should be true
console.log(multiIncludes(text, values2)); // should be false
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure that you OK with regex but you can done this in regex. Also you can expand that solution for AND OR logic if you want.

```js
let str = "hay needle stack overflow"

let s0 = "hay"
let s1 = "needle"

// (?=.*{value}) syntax required for matching without order
// maybe join('') can be replaced to join('|') for OR behaviour
let matches = str.match([s0,s1].map(d=>`(?=.*${d})`).join(''))

console.log("matches:", matches != null)
```

Comment: Building a regex using concatenation of unknown values can produce unexpected results. For example, what happens if `s0 = 'h|y'`? The code decides that `str` contains `s0` but this is obviously incorrect. What if `s0 = 'hay('`? The regular expression is invalid and `str.match()` throws a [`SyntaxError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError). Also, `join('')` produces `matches === null` if the values of `s0` and `s1` are swapped.