# Why isn't my h3 element content matching with the array contents?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i am trying to make a script that changes the link of an image to a new image within a div if the h2 element contains any of the text within the array `const targetTexts`. there is an issue with the if statement, if i remove the part  `&& targetTexts.includes(h3Element.textContent.toLowerCase()`, which i need to check against the words in the array, and leave it as and leave it as `if (h3Element)` , it works and replaces every single image with the new image. but, i need to check the contents of the h2 element against the array so i need that line.

the h3 element textContent outputs stuff like this : "Beauty in motion Attractive young mixed race woman in jeans shirt shaking  her head and smiling while standing outdoors, Generative AI 29139243 Stock  Photo at Vecteezy"
so i dont get why its not working if there is matches

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('SCRIPT BEGINS RUNNING');
  // select all search results
  const results = document.querySelectorAll('div[jsname="N9Xkfe"]');
  const aiImg = 'https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/anti-ai-sign-no-aigenerated-600nw-2289609093.jpg';
  console.log(results);

  // array of targeted text
  const targetTexts = [
    'ai', 'ai generated', 'generate ai', 'ai art',
    'stable diffusion', 'midjourney', 'generative ai',
    'ai-generated'
  ];

  // loop through each result element
  results.forEach(result => {
    // check if the element has an h2 child with targeted text
    const h3Element = result.querySelector('h3');
    console.log('H3 ELEMENT' + h3Element.textContent);
    console.log('FOR EACH LOOP BEGINS');

    if (h3Element && targetTexts.includes(h3Element.textContent.toLowerCase())) {
      // get the img element and replace the link
      console.log('THE H2 ELEMENT EXISTS!!!');
      const imgSrc = result.querySelector('img');
      console.log('IMAGE SRC: ' + imgSrc);
      imgSrc.setAttribute('src', aiImg);
    }

    console.log('FOR EACH LOOP ENDS');

  });

  console.log('END OF SCRIPT');
}, 2000);
```

and here is an example of the console logs which i used to confirm i was selecting the correct elements:

[image]

Comment: Please show also the console logs.

Comment: i just added them, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you implemented is checking if any `targetText` elements contains the full H3 element text content. You need to separate the text content into smaller pieces to check if those smaller pieces match and not the whole thing.

I see that the H3 element content text has segments separated by a comma (`,`) or a pipe (`|`) but very sporadically, so you could split the content and check individually for each segment.

```
if (!h3Element) return;

const fullTextContent = h3Element.textContent?.toLowerCase() || "";

/**
 * splitting just by a comma
 * feel free to tune this as you see fit
 */
const textContents = fullTextContent.split(", ").map((t) => t.toLowerCase());

/**
 * now we check if any of the `targetTexts` elements are 
 * included in any of those splitted text contents
 */
if (targetTexts.some(target => textContents.includes(target)) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `targetTexts.includes(h3Element.textContent.toLowerCase())` is problematic.

```js
const targetTexts = [
    'ai', 'ai generated', 'generate ai', 'ai art',
    'stable diffusion', 'midjourney', 'generative ai',
    'ai-generated'
  ];

  const h3ElementTextContent = 'Beauty in motion Attractive young mixed race woman in jeans shirt shaking her head and smiling while standing outdoors, Generative AI 29139243 Stock Photo at Vecteezy'; // copied from the question
  if (targetTexts.includes(h3ElementTextContent.toLowerCase())) {
      console.log('The string exists');
  } else {
      console.log('The string does not exist');
  }
```

It will return `the string does not exist`, as `Array.includes()` does not work this way. If we change the `h3ElementTextContent` to "AI", the check will match, as the word "AI" lowercased is included in the `targetTexts` array.

You should change the checking to (requires ES5+):

```js
const targetTexts = [
    'ai', 'ai generated', 'generate ai', 'ai art',
    'stable diffusion', 'midjourney', 'generative ai',
    'ai-generated'
];

str = 'Beauty in motion Attractive young mixed race woman in jeans shirt shaking her head and smiling while standing outdoors, Generative AI 29139243 Stock Photo at Vecteezy';
  
if (targetTexts.some(function(v) { return str.toLowerCase().indexOf(v) >= 0; })) {
    console.log('The string exists');
} else {
    console.log('The string does not exist');
}
```

This will return `The string exists`.

Alternatively, you can use RegEx. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5582621/188331) for more details.